# @extends doesn't work in Webstorm with Stylus

Tags: webstorm, stylus

I try to the the @extend function from Stylus in Webstorm,  however, I cannot get it to work.

Example:

```
   .icon-right
      color #fff
      width 35px
      height 35px
      line-height 40px
      font-size 1.4em
      text-align center
      position absolute
      top 35%
      left -4%


.icon-right-2
    @extends .icon-right
    background-color #999
```

Output:

```
/usr/local/bin/stylus stylus.styl

/usr/local/lib/node_modules/stylus/bin/stylus:545
          throw err;
                ^
Error: stylus.styl:227
 223| 
 224| 
 225|     .icon-righ-new
 226|       @extends .icon-right
```

> 227| 
>        228| 
>        229|

```
Failed to @extend ".icon-right"

    at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/stylus/lib/visitor/normalizer.js:214:24
    at Array.forEach (native)
at Normalizer.extend (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/stylus/lib/visitor/normalizer.js:212:28)
at Normalizer.visitGroup (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/stylus/lib/visitor/normalizer.js:137:8)
at Normalizer.Visitor.visit (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/stylus/lib/visitor/index.js:28:40)
at Normalizer.visitBlock (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/stylus/lib/visitor/normalizer.js:112:19)
at Normalizer.Visitor.visit (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/stylus/lib/visitor/index.js:28:40)
at Normalizer.visitGroup (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/stylus/lib/visitor/normalizer.js:139:22)
at Normalizer.Visitor.visit (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/stylus/lib/visitor/index.js:28:40)
at Normalizer.visitBlock (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/stylus/lib/visitor/normalizer.js:112:19)
```

I've tried a different approaches but I recieve the same error. Other Stylus function and Nib are working.

Comment: your code works fine for me (I'm using Stylus version 0.42.3). And it's correctly parsed by WebStorm (note that the errors you reported come from stylus compiler, not from WebStorm itself). What stylus version do you use?

Comment: I've tried 0.37 and 0.42.3. If in your case the code is correctly parsed then the probably must be something with my setup.

Comment: In your example above, the `.icon-right` class is tabbed one level deeper than the `.icon-right-2` class. On it's own this compiles fine, but if this declaration is nested inside something else, that could account for the failure.